# How to change interval time in collectd?

Tags: configuration, monitoring

How do I change the collection interval time in collectd? I want it to collect my data every 1 second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via `Interval`

from [`man collectd.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/collectd.conf.5.html)

```
Interval Seconds
   Configures the interval in which to query the read plugins.
   Obviously smaller values lead to a higher system load produced by
   collectd, while higher values lead to more coarse statistics.
```

---

eg:

```
<LoadPlugin df>
    Interval 1
</LoadPlugin>
```

Comment: HI, thank you for your comment. I have another question though. Is there anyway that I can log usage of cpu, memory, etc in collectd? I know 'kcollectd' lets you see graphically but I want to log those usages lively. Thank you in advance

Comment: My answer is an answer, not a comment. And please, be fair. Ask a new question if you have more things to ask. Answer and questions in contents are annoying for the other readers. ;)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)